# Mailer replacing domain name with webmaster email (namecheap and gmail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, railscasts

I'm trying to set up a password reset mailer following this railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast.

I am able to get my mailer to send emails after following the heroku blog to set up my environment. Please note I'm using namecheap for my domain and gmail/google apps to handle my emails.
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail/

The problem I'm having though is that the emails I'm receiving is replacing my email where the domain name should be. See below:

```
To reset your password, click the URL below.

http://webmaster@mydomain.com/password_resets/qVwzCsKHZA-VS6GyDTTyQw/edit
```

I want it to be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/password_resets/qVwzCsKHZA-VS6GyDTTyQw/edit
```

**How do I get the mailer to show the domain name instead of the webmaster email?**

I've already checked my code numerous time and I think it's simply a matter of some type of forwarding issue. Let me know if you want me to post any relevant code up.

This is in my production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "webmaster@mydomain.com" }
```

password_resets_controller.rb

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Email sent with password reset"
end
```

user.rb

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "webmaster@mysite.com"


  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset"
  end
end
```

password_reset.text.erb

```
To reset your password, click the URL below.
<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about the code that creates that link (and if you are using `default_url_options` rather than passing :host, what is that set to?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Added the code per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your host to whatever your domain name is and it should work: 
   :host => "mydomain.com"